# Object going out of scope

Tags: c#, reference, garbage-collection

We have code like below to fix CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx). When the tbl is assigned null, will the object that it referenced garbage collected ?

```
    private DataTable BuildRequestDataTable(Factory tableFactory)
    {
        DataTable tbl = null;
        DataTable requestTable = null;
        try
        {
            tbl = tableFactory.CreateTable();
            requestTable = tbl;
            tbl = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tbl != null)
            {
                tbl.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return requestTable;
    }
```

Comment: It seems this entire method could just be `return tableFactory.CreateTable()`.

Comment: @hatchet - It won't be disposed if the try block completes successfully since `tbl` will be null.

Comment: I can't see any case where the Dispose would actually execute. It could only happen on an exception thrown in `requestTable=tbl` or `tbl=null`, neither of which seem likely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When the tbl is assigned null, will the object that it referenced garbage collected ?

No. Or at least, not immediately. Objects aren't reference-counted like that.

It's not really clear why you're juggling all those variables at all - I can't see how you'd *ever* end up disposing of anything. Either the `CreateTable` call succeeds, in which case the following two statements will succeed and nothing will be disposed, or the `CreateTable` call throws, in which case `tbl` will still be null and nothing will be disposed.

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
private DataTable BuildRequestDataTable(Factory tableFactory)
{
    return tableFactory.CreateTable();
}
```

At that point you may well get a warning that you're not disposing of the `DataTable`, but that's deliberate - the caller would presumably take responsibility for disposing it.

Of course at this point it's not clear that the code is really providing much benefit itself - it's no easier to use:

```
using (var table = BuildRequestDataTable(tableFactory))
```

than

```
using (var table = tableFactory.CreateTable())
```

... unless you're planning to add more logic in the method.

Comment: what do you mean by Objects aren't reference-counted like that ?

Comment: @aziz: I mean that when you assign the value `null` to `tbl`, that doesn't cause an internal count to be decremented. The garbage collector just finds all reachable objects whenever it runs, and cleans up the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to return the DataTable in this method, why are disposing it then?
Caller is now responsible for disposing this DataTable.

Your method should simply be:

```
private DataTable BuildRequestDataTable(Factory tableFactory) 
{ 
   return tableFactory.CreateTable();        
}
```

Comment: I agree - the entire method seems to be unnecessary.